# Security restriction: how to save the results of a database query to a local file?

Tags: apache-flex, security, service, save

I'm having some trouble getting around a security restriction of flex.

Saving a file is apparently an action that can only be invoked upon user interaction.

The problem is that after my user clicks on the save button, I need to perform a database query to get the data for the file I want to save.

Because Flex works asynchronous, I have to make the database call and then catch the ResultEvent in a different function.

In that function, I no longer have the user's mouseclick event. How am I then supposed to save this file?

Example:

```
protected function saveFile(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     ROWrapper.Controller.loadData();
}

protected function onDataLoaded(event:ResultEvent):void
{
     var XMLdata:XML = event.result as XML;
     var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
     fr.save(XMLdata);
}


<s:Button x="283" y="254" label="Save" click="saveFile(event)"/>
```

Comment: posting a sample code might help you to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you display the result set first in a data grid, and then enable a button called "Download", once the data has been returned, and stored in a array object?

This way the user can "preview" the data, and once happy, download the data directly from the cached array object, or from the Data Grid's data set.